How do you bundle config files when building with Tauri + Svelte?
I want to make the config.json file of my Tauri app available for users so that they can modify its properties on the fly like you would with a .net app. For example, users might want to change the exported file save location.
The Tauri documentation states that I should add the path to the resources tag in the tauri.conf.json file to include the file in the application bundle:
"resources": ["../public/config.json"]
But this won't work because the documentation also says:
Absolute paths and paths containing parent components (../) can only be allowed via "$RESOURCE/*". Relative paths like "path/to/file.txt" can be allowed explicitly via "$RESOURCE/path/to/file.txt".
Unfortunately, I don't understand what that means. I've tried this and this doesn't work either:
"resources": ["$RESOURCE/public/config.json"],
to be clear, the tauri.conf.json file is in the src-tauri folder and the config file I want to bundle is in the public folder.
What is the correct way to provide editable json config files to users using tauri and how do I make it work?
